# band folding instead of unfolding

Tags: band-structure

I'm wondering if there is any easy way to fold the band structure from unit cell BZ to supercell BZ. For example, I have a 2D rectangular lattice and its band structure along $\Gamma - X - Y - \Gamma$ within the first BZ. Now, I would like to see the band dispersion along $\Gamma - X$ for the lattice replicated several times along $y$.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been almost 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!